# Why do some words contain "let"?

Tags: vocabulary, let

outlet, booklet, tablet... Are there any other word that contains a conjugation of "let" with other words? Why do these words contain let? If not coincidental, what is the significant meaning of let in these words?

Comment: A list of words here : http://www.morewords.com/ends-with-by-length/let/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though all three words you've mentioned contain *let*, that doesn't mean that they have something in common.

1. *outlet* comes from two words: *out* and the verb *let* (see [this](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&q=outlet%20etymology&spell=1&rct=j) Google search).
2. *booklet* comes from two things: the noun *book* and the suffix *-let* that means *small*, *lesser* and comes from Old French (see [this](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-let) page for proof).
3. *tablet* comes from two words: the noun *table* and the Old French word *tablete* (again, check out [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=tablet&oq=tablet&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.920j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=tablet+etymology) Google search).

So, the three words all having *let* at the end is just a coincidence.

Comment: Under **tablet**, OED has ***table** n. + -**ete , -ette -et** suffix*, so arguably *booklet* and *tablet* do have "something in common". But **wallet**, for example, is almost certainly unconnected.